# My system seems stuck on Optimize hard drive in FileVault

Tags: macos, hard-drive, macbook-pro, filevault

Just upgraded to Yosemite. Going through the process it asked about file vault. I said yes to encrypt it, so it started to optimize hard drive it seems to be stuck on 2 hours left....probably been 3 hours since it started. What do I do? Thank you in advance (I am new to Apple products btw.)

Answer (score 1):

Encrypting can take hours depending on the size of the information on your disk.

Run following in terminal to see the status of encryption `diskutil cs list`